# How do I get the coordinates for the edges of a hexagon without rounding errors?

Tags: math, canvas, geometry, kineticjs, rounding-error

I need to generate 6 coordinates(x,y) in JavaScript, representing the edges of a hexagon, but I need the results to be free of "rounding errors", how do I accomplish this? When I have rounding errors there is some unwanted space between the circles drawn at the coordinates if the hexagon is large enough, or in other words they don't align themselves together accurately.

Perhaps the math used to calculate the coordinates needs to be free from certain methods like cos or sin perhaps? But if not, what are my options? I tried expressing the math using BigDecimal (https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) but it didn't seem to change anything, though perhaps I'm using it wrong and I'd rather not have to use it.

Ineffective Method 1: http://jsbin.com/ekuyam/2/edit

Ineffective Method 2: http://jsbin.com/ekuyam/4/edit

Small:

[image]

Large:

[image]

Comment: You can't draw a regular hexagon exactly on a discretized screen; you can only make it look good. (cos π/3, sin π/3) = (1/2, √3/2).

Comment: @EricJablow So is it possible to make it look better then in the picture above or is that the best that can be done? I'm afraid I don't understand what "(cos π/3, sin π/3) = (1/2, √3/2)" means exactly or how it applies to my problem, does applying it in some way to my code make the circles align better?

Comment: It's possible; you will need to approximate the coordinates, and the polygon will be only close to regular. Finding the coordinates of a regular polygon requires simple trigonometry.